# Missing View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

The 'View Controller' used to show on 'Show the Size Inspector' so I can change the 'Simulating Size', where is it?

I've tried the help, it gave me what is shown in the picture

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose View > Utilities > Attributes Inspector
[image: like this]

Click on this blue highlighted button
[image: Click on this blue highlighted button]

Comment: When I go to View > Utilities > Attributes Inspector .. the Simulated Metrics doesn't show

Comment: Click on the right icon if you aren't. You're probably clicking the icon which is right to it.

Comment: Okay, the Simulated Metrics is not there

Comment: You have to **Select the view controller you want to configure by clicking it in the outline view or on the canvas** and then click on blue highlighted button.